# Fourier transform of exponential function

Tags: exponential-function, inverse, fourier-transform

It is a function $A(f,t)= e^{j 2 \pi (t/a-af)}$
I would like to take the inverse Fourier transform.

So:

$B(\tau,t)=\int A(f,t) e^{j2\pi f\tau}df=\delta(\tau-t_0)...???$

How to solve this integral?
 Or should I use $e^{j 2 \pi (t/a)}$ as constant?

Comment: The delta function expression is right, what is the reason that you doubt that?

Comment: @Aminopterin   i am not sure how to solve this integral. If i take that exp(i2 pi (t/a) is constant, shoud I multiply with delta function ( delta(t) or delta (tau)) as fourier transform of constant?

Comment: Yes, Fourier transform is linear, you should multiply the constant.

Comment: @Aminopterin  i have done the calculation, but if i take fourier transform of result I didnt get the same function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just recognize that, I think,
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{f \to t'} \exp \left[ 2\pi j \left( \frac{t}{a}-af \right) \right]
= e^{2\pi j t/a} \delta ( t'-a )
$$
if $t$ does not depend on $f$.
Also, there are several different conventions on FT, you have to specify, but usually they differ up to a constant multiple. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms) formula 102, 302)

Comment: how do you get delta function in the answer? I got exp(j pi f (t´-a).

Comment: Have you seen the Wiki table formula 102, 302?

Comment: i have seen, but it is for fourier transform, in my case is  inverse FT.  I don`t understand how do you and Mostafa Ayaz get delta function.

Comment: I got the same answer with you, but instead ofdelta i got exp

Comment: Try to read the table ``from right to left``, since the Wiki convention is symmetrical. If you still got questions, post your calculation in the question body so we can see.

Comment: i got it, i forgot that it is the definite integral...thanks a lot

Comment: But I think it should be $\delta(t´+a)$..?

Comment: I think I am right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's right and you should consider $t$ as constant and define a new, independent variable $\tau$ for **time**. The model in which the Fourier transform changes with some other variable ($t$ in this case) can be used for example **to model a time-variant communication channel**. In that case, even the channel is modeled stochastically with its FT dependent to time. In that case, **the power spectral density is used as the FT of stochastic channel response** and therefore varies with time, i.e. $$h(\tau;t)=\text{channel response varying over time}\\S(f;t)=\int E\{h(\tau+\tau_1;t)h(\tau_1;t)\}e^{-i2\pi f\tau_1}d\tau_1$$where $E\{\cdot\}$ stands for **mathematical expectation** and channel is assumed to be **a stationary process**.

Comment: in my case, I got exp(i pi (t/a) as constant, but Should i take delta(t) as fourier tansform of constant?

Comment: No you shouldn't since the FT is 1D only taken over $\tau$. $t$ can only be parameter of change in $A(f;t)$ (no matter what the origination is, even it can be else than *time*). Also in your question it should be $$B(\tau,t)=\int A(f,t) e^{j2\pi f\tau}df$$not$$B(\tau,t)=\int A(f,t) e^{j2\pi ft}df$$and you should double-check your final answer (an exponential factor is neglected)

Comment: $B(\tau,t)=\int e^{j2\pi (t/a-fa)} e^{j2\pi f\tau}df=e^{j2\pi (t/a)}\int e^{j2\pi f(\tau-a)} df=(e^{j2\pi (t/a)}/(j2\pi (\tau-a)))e^{j2\pi f(\tau-a)}$...is it right?

Comment: Right. But you can write alternatively $$\int e^{j2\pi f(\tau-a)df}=\delta(\tau+a)$$

Comment: how do you get this? Why does the integration of exponential function equal to dirac?

Comment: This is one assumption we do. In two ways, we can argue this. $(1)$ first, we define $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos 2\pi fdf=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2\pi fdf=0\implies \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(j2\pi f\tau)df=0$$as long as $\tau\ne 0$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(j2\pi f\tau)df=\infty$$for $\tau =0$ but the type of $\infty$ here is like that in $\delta(u) $ for $u=0$ (to see why, we should find a sequence of functions tending to $\delta(t)$, calculate the FT and see the result)

Comment: (2) Another argument is that $$\int_{\Bbb R} \delta(t-t_0)\exp(-j2\pi ft)dt=\exp(-j2\pi ft_0)$$therefore$$\delta(t-t_0)\iff \exp(-j2\pi ft_0)$$then by duality$$\exp(j2\pi f_0t)\iff \delta(f-f_0)$$(I think this one is stronger)

Comment: if i take $F(\delta(\tau+a))= exp(j \pi fa)$

Comment: Yes which can be proved using the definition of FT.

Comment: ok, but they are not same...$exp(j\pi f a)$ is not same with$ exp(j 2 \pi f(\tau-a))$

Comment: The $\exp(2\pi f(\tau-a))$ serves as the integrand (and can't even exist beyond integral), the outcome result does **not** depend on $\tau$. Also $a$ is a constant that does not play an active role in integrating the exponential term.

Comment: how does it not depend on $\tau$? $exp(2 \pi f(**\tau**-a)$? and the integral is taken by  df, so how i understand integration of exp(f)df=exp(f), right?

Comment: Sorry. My bad, but do you agree that the FT of $\delta(\tau-\tau_0)$ is $e^{-i2\pi f\tau_0}$?

Comment: yes. i agree with that

Comment: Now what about this: duality states that$$e^{-i2\pi t\tau_0}\iff \delta(f+\tau_0)$$?

Comment: i got it. I forgot that i have the definite integral....thanks a lot

Comment: Your welcome. Wish you luck!!